# Extension to web server to write scripts using C++?

Tags: c++, scripting, webserver

Well I was wondering if there is any extension for a web server which allows me to "script" in C++ instead of a scripting language like php?

some pseudo code:

```
#include <iostream>

cout << "<html><title>this is a webpage</title></html>";
```

I know this sounds silly but I am really wondering if such thing exists.

Or maybe there is something that allows to run compiled C++ code as a webpage from a web server?

Comment: "PHP server" is a non sequitur, unless you're talking about the PHP 5.4 built-in dev server, which you most certainly aren't from the context.  What does this actually have to do with PHP?  Are you just looking for a quick and dirty C++-based web application framework ... thing?

Comment: What web server are you using? Most are not php specific and allow you to generate pages pretty much any way you want.

Comment: yeah just looking for a quick way for generating pages from C++ instead of PHP scripts, the webserver I hired has cgi and php support, but I don't think it allows custom extensions to be loaded. have to check that out. But it would be cool to play with it on localhost

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are trying to work out how you can configure a web server, which is currently configured for PHP, to serve the output of a program you have written in C++. If you can confirm, you're liking looking at writing CGI scripts in C++. Take a look at http://www.geekdaily.net/2007/08/06/c-a-basic-cgi-tutorial/

Comment: @Gam, if your host supports CGI, then you have your answer.  CGI is an API (well, specification, whatever), and any old program can implement it, from a freaking DOS batch file to, well, C++.

Comment: oh lol CGI is the answer, CGI does have all the C++11 features?

Comment: @GamErix CGI has no concept of C++, it's just a standardized method for a web server to delegate the generation of a web page to some other executable. You can create that executable using whatever method you wish, including C++11.

Comment: em, how would I run a CGI script which has this: `#include <iostream.h>void main(){cout << "Content-type: text/plain" << "Hello, World!";}` ? I try to run it in my localhost/file.cgi but I get an http 500 error :$

Comment: @GamErix CGI will run any type of executable file, be it a script with an interpreter directive (`!#`) or a binary executable. So for C++ you would compile your code and put that executable wherever you want the cgi program to be.

Comment: Oh thanks works :D well back to cross compatibility programming in C++, no more msvc stuff hehe :F

Comment: You can write a PHP extension in C++... This loads like any other PHP extension, and is available as a PHP function like any other PHP function.  Alternatively, if you are using Apache (or IIS), you can write an Apache (or IIS) extension, which instructs Apache (or IIS) to route certain requests to your extension (which can be written in  C++).  The latter approach is more difficult because it requires some non-trivial setup in the C++ code.  I have utilized both of these approaches for commercial clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as said in comments you can do what you want using CGI. If your need is to make a webapp using c++, WT is probably the framework you want :

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt